# Quando usar possui e possuí

Tags: ortografia, verbos

Gostaria de saber em que casos utilizo acento na palavra possui, pois não encontrei uma resposta coerente em minhas buscas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O termo "possui" é a forma singular da **terceira** pessoa do **presente** do modo indicativo do verbo "possuir".

Já termo "possuí" é a forma singular da **primeira** pessoa do **pretérito perfeito** do modo indicativo do verbo "possuir".

Desta forma, você utiliza a palavra "possui" quando o ato de possuir se refere a outrem e é um acontecimento presente. Por exemplo:

> João possui uma bola dentro de seu armário.

Já a forma "possuí" se aplica ao passado, quando quem tinha posse de alguma coisa era você mesmo. Por exemplo:

> Eu possuí 24 cartas no decorrer do jogo.